# Confusion: different definitions of MAP estimation in Graphical Models (MRFs)

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, graphical-model

1. The "classical" MAP estimation: $$\hat\theta = \arg\max_{\theta}P(\theta|\mathbf{x})$$ where $\mathbf{x}$ are the observations and $\theta$ are the parameters.
2. In this [book chapter](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/9780262015776_sch_0001.pdf) (page 6, second item), MAP estimation for a MRF is to maximize $P(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{z},\theta)$ w.r.t $\mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is the sequence of states, $\mathbf{z}$ is the set of observed data.
3. In this [paper](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4165-map-estimation-for-graphical-models-by-likelihood-maximization) (page 2), that is to maximize $P(\mathbf{x}|\theta)$.

I would appreciate it if somebody could make the connection among these three clearer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imho, the usual MAP problem is $\arg\max_x P(x|z)$ for some evidence $z$. This is considering the parameters of the model as fixed (parameters are usually $\theta$). This means MAP is the most probably assignment to the non-observed variables, *after* observing $z$. Not this is equivalent to your point 1 up to variable renaming (though it's a quite unusual renaming, considering the usual naming scheme). So I'm more with point 2., if you want to have the parameters also visible.

Comment: Hi @ziggystar, 
In the point 1, $\theta$ are the parameters (I've updated the question), and this is actually the usual MAP.

Comment: I've looked into the book by Koller and Friedman. And it appears you're right. But there are two different things (which I also mixed up). They call MAP **estimation** when estimating parameters; then they give your formula 1. But there is also the MAP **query**, asking for the most probable assignment; and this is what I thought of, and it is defined by your second formula, if you also want to have the parameters visible (which you usually don't in this case).

Comment: Yes, @ziggystar. I can see it more clearly now. What leads to the confusion is just the naming (MAP estimation everywhere :s). 
Indeed, as you said, in the first point, **MAP estimation** stands for the estimation of the parameters $\theta$ by maximizing the posterior probability $P(\theta|\mathbf{x})$. 
In the second point, according to Koller and Friedman's book, that is **MAP assignment* or **most probable explanation (MPE)**, which is to ﬁnd _the most probable assignment to all non-evidence variables_.
The third point is similar to the second, where there is no observed data.

next...

Comment: Now it remains one thing that is still not clear for me: in the first point, $P(\theta|\mathbf{x})$ is called the **posterior probability**, while in the third point, $P(\mathbf{x}|\theta)$ has the same name (?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confusion shows that you are a very exact person!  ;-)

Assumptions on the notation: 
 - $\theta $: Parameters 
 - $ \mathbf{x} , \mathbf{z} $: Variables

Among **Bayesian** people, when someone talks about *estimation*, they refer to estimation of almost anything. See this: 
ftp://ftp.cs.utoronto.ca/pub/radford/bayes-tut.pdf
In Neal's tutorial, page 4 he estimates the parameters of the model, given input data, using the probability of the posterior. Finding the maximizer will give you the most-probable estimates (your 1st definition).
\n

See, your 2nd and 3rd definition are basically the same. In some applications you might have some input $z$, which is usually known. Given the parameter $\theta$, the probability of seeing $X = x$ is: 
$$
p(X = x | Z = z , \Theta = \theta)
$$
The most probable observation is (you second defintion) :
$$
\arg\max_{x} p(X = x | Z = z , \Theta = \theta)
$$
\n

In a model, assume you don't have any input (like mixture of gaussians model). Given the parameter $\theta$, the probability of seeing $X = x$ is: 
$$
p(X = x | \Theta = \theta)
$$
The most probable observation is (your third defintion) :
$$
\arg\max_{x} p(X = x | \Theta = \theta)
$$

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for the answer.
I agree with you on what you said about _estimation_ (as I have commented in replying to @ziggystar in the first post), but how about _MAP_? 
In the first point, $P(\theta|\mathbf{x})$ is called the **posterior probability**, while in the third point, $P(\mathbf{x}|\theta)$ has the same name. Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: Yes, in fact all of these can be posterior distributions. Depending on how you model, all of these can be posterior, thus MAP. Though, sometimes people just refer to solving similar stuff, as MAP; (even if the probability is not really a posterior probability; a common mistake)